# Broken Nvida-Driver-455 Package On Fresh Install of Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, package-management

I just did a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 on my machine (win10 dual, secureboot on, achi drivers activated in bios, fastboot off):

```
Machine :  Acer Aspire 5 (A5 515-55g).
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1035G1 CPU @ 1.00GHz
Memory  : 7923MB (5740MB used)
Resolution  : 1920x1080 pixels
OpenGL Renderer : GeForce MX350/PCIe/SSE2 (Nvidia driver 450 proprietary)
Gnome-shell version: 3.36.8
```

I immediately did all of the software / firmware updates and rebooted the machine.  The problem is that when I run 'sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall' , it outputs:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-driver-455 : Depends: nvidia-kernel-source-455 (= 455.38-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

When I open "Software and Updates" it shows that nvidia-driver-455 is installed and available for use (but it defaults to nvidia-driver-450).

[image]

**Solutions that I have tried:**

`sudo apt remove nvidia-drvier-455`  (can't be removed because it is NOT installed)

`sudo apt install -f`  (has zero effect doesn't recognize a broken package)

`sudo apt install synaptic` -. "Fix Broken Packages"  (no effect, additionally synaptic does not recognize that nvidia-driver-455 is installed)

Synaptic search for "nvidia-driver-455"

[image]

I select any item, "Mark For Installation" is the only option and nvidia-driver-450 must be removed, so I don't do it. :-)

NOTE: I don't know if this relevant, but under 18.04.. the virtualbox dkms  and mesa/vulkan drivers seemed to conflict with other and I could never get both to work simultaneously (fixing one broke the other).

In any case, scratching my head on this.. any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get remove 'nvidia.*'
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-455
```

And I recommend to disable Secure Boot.

Comment: With / without `` sudo apt remove 'nvidia.*', outputs: `E: Unable to locate package nvidia.*
`

Comment: That's OK. Run the next command.

Comment: Oops, now it's not a regexp. Hold on.

Comment: crap.. already started

Comment: No problem. If it is finished OK, then never mind.

Comment: Question, I run a dual-boot.. and I need win10 on a daily basis for a course I teach.. doesn't win10 require secureboot... will turning it off means that I need to enter bios going back forth between OS?

Comment: No, Windows doesn't require Secure Boot.

Comment: I followed the instructions.. rebooted, updated, rebooted, disabled secureboot, and ran `sudo apt autoremove` which said that it removed nvidia-driver-450-common. Now we seem to have "reversed the same problem.  https://imgur.com/a/23R7KBI   and https://imgur.com/a/Dmxp5Ug   "Software & Updates" shows a "ghost" drivers for 450 that I cannot remove, but good news..  `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` no longer shows broken packages. :-/.

Comment: Also something weird.  I am based in Asia so the Server for China is most convenient for me.  Upon first boot I changed the "Region" settings to English, so as to avoid having to constantly read Chinese (which I actually can :).  Anyway, the first boot following your advice and now shows the date in Chinese on the login screen.  After I login, correctly in English.

Comment: I will install and run memtester again, as I know the "new clock displaying chinese error" will become much worst if ignored.  If memtester doesn't work, I will post a new question about ghost drivers and testing memory.